# NSUserDefaults not changing default value

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I asked a question about this that was originally answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606358/save-high-score-for-iphone-app). Originally, I checked the first answer as the best one, but for the sake of simplicity, I ended up using `NSUserDefaults`. The problem, though, is that the default value in question is not changing after I assign it a value during startup, even when I use `setObject: forKey:`. Here's the code:

```
//In MenuViewController.m
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    NSDictionary* dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:10] forKey:@"highscore"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dictionary];

    NSLog(@"%d", [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"highscore"] intValue]);

    //Unrelated code

}
```

From there, a game session runs, and when the session is over, this code is implemented:

```
-(void)timeUp{
    statsView= [[StatViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"StatViewController" bundle:nil];
    statsView.score=score;
    int highScore = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"highscore"] intValue];
    if (highScore < score)
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:score] forKey: @"highScore"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        NSLog(@"%d", [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"highscore"] intValue]);
    }
    highScore = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"highscore"];
}
```

And then in StatViewController:

```
//highScoreLabel is a UILabel that's set up through IB
highScoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"highscore"] intValue]];
```

I've registered the NSUserDefaults and even use synchronize, but the console always shows the value being 10. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keys are case sensitive!

You're setting `highScore` although you always read in `highscore`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:score] forKey: @"highScore"];
```

When you are setting the score here, you use the key @"highScore".

When you read the key, you use @"highscore". Change the first one to @"highscore" and it should work.